# VB.NET Unloading and reloading a project when executing a program through the Visual Studio External Tools

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a software that is executed through the External tools of Visual Studio, and it changes some stuff in the loaded project.
But the modifications only appear after I reload the project in my solution.

Is there any way of automatically unload and reload a project through the program that I made?

Comment: Maybe add some more information, such as any code you have already written.

Comment: I have tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/managing-project-loading-in-a-solution?view=vs-2019 , but it didn't work. Probably because it was meant to be used when building a extension.